# distance matrix on huge dataset on R

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, distance, hierarchical-clustering

I have a huge dataset containing (1 382 400 datas). I have to do distance to do a HAC on it but when I do

```
dist(dataset)
```

I have the error :

> cannot allocate vector of size 197.8 Gb

but my datas size si 1,1MB

What can I do to make it work ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Imagine you have 3 points. A naive distance matrix will have the dimensions (3*3). One which only stores half the values (as it's symmetrical) and does not store the diagonal would have (3*3-3)/2. You have 1.4m points. Have you calculated the approximate dimensions of your output matrix? Imagine (slightly optimistically) that each value can be stored in 4 bytes. How much space do you need? It's worth considering calculating the distances in batches and saving the output to disk.

Comment: What is HAC? here.

Comment: I'm assuming HAC = hierarchical agglomerative clustering. What package/function are you using to do the clustering? The `agnes` package doesn't require a distance/dissimilarity matrix. Also, depending on the link type, HAC may need only the nearest neighbor. The `FNN` library can return nearest neighbors very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fastclustering` library. There is a `hclust.vector` function which uses the memory efficient algorithm and avoid invocation of `dist` function. However,  take patience, it took me 76 ms to make clustering for 10000 observations w/6 columns. So in case you have 100 times more observations it roughly takes 10000 times longer to calculate, at least. Unfortunately, no magic - saving space you increase time (see comment by SamR above).

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(fastcluster)

# Generating sample with ~ 80 thousand elements
# takes 80 ms 
elements = 13824L
cols = 6L
x <- matrix(rnorm(elements), ncol = cols, nrow = elements / cols)
microbenchmark(fastcluster::hclust.vector(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# fastcluster::hclust.vector(x) 73.3258 75.14525 76.12058 75.8676 76.9658 80.7951   100

# Generating sample with ~ 1,3 mln elements
elements = 1382400L
cols = 6L
x <- matrix(rnorm(elements), ncol = cols, nrow = elements / cols)

# Built-in clustering
stats::hclust(dist(x))
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 197.8 Gb

# Using fastcluster library
fastcluster::hclust.vector(x)
# Take care, may take more than a hour
# I was not that patient :)
```